# JSP code to ensure that Mozilla Firefox browser doesn't cache a web page?

Tags: jsp, firefox, caching, browser, mozilla

I am trying to ensure that Mozilla Firefox browser doesn't cache a web page by adding following jsp code to add cache clear headers.

```
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
   response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
   response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
```

Mozilla browser still shows the cached version of the page.

Please suggest the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your code, one way of ensuring pages are not cached is by adding random tokens to URLs that have no functionality. i.e. If the path to this page of yours is accessed by a generated URL have the URL contain a random token such `?token=[blah]`. This will make the browser "think" it's a new page every time and will not displayed a cached version.